# Still cannot access web-site by POST

Tags: python, post, web-crawler, payload

I would like to get store info from the web-site(http://www.hilife.com.tw/storeInquiry_street.aspx).
The method I found by chrome is POST.
By using below method, I still cannot access.
Could someone give me a hint?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
head = {
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {
'__EVENTTARGET':'AREA',
'__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
'__LASTFOCUS':'',
'__VIEWSTATE':'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',
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'B77476FC',
'__EVENTVALIDATION':'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',
'CITY':'台中市',
'AREA':'北區'
}

res = requests.post('http://www.hilife.com.tw/storeInquiry_street.aspx', data=payload, headers = head)
res.encoding = 'utf-8'
print res.text
```

Comment: system `'Linux deb-host 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux` python `Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
your code work.

Comment: Code worked for me too. What error do you get?

Comment: I always get this...  
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: ""
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are missing this : `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you have to send a header like this as well as send data in x-www-form-urlencoded format .  I recommend using POSTMAN for testing before writing the code. Also make sure you have relevant permission before crawling third party website. Happy Crawling.

Comment: Excuse me, I still cannot make it. The system always replies "The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.".    It's very strange...

Comment: Try POSTMAN, I was getting response there.

Comment: Can you switch to other city and area successfully? I always get the default city and area... :(

Comment: Sorry I cannot read it . ITs all in another language so not getting whether its right response.